# Could I turn into a nuclear bomb?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, atoms

Just out of curiousity, could the nuclei of our atoms split via quantum tunnelling, thereby leading to nuclear reactions and ultimately turning us into atomic bombs? I know that this is near-impossible, but wondering if it was *technically* possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, we're made of mostly stable matter of low atomic number. In a nuclear bomb, unstable nuclei split, releasing a number of energetic neutrons which strike other unstable nuclei, and the reactions chain uncontrollably. Splitting a small nucleus actually costs energy, so even if a carbon atom in your body did split, it would only split into smaller, still low-energy atoms, which would interact normally with other atoms in your body. A couple extra lithium or helium atoms isn't going to do anything drastic.

Answer (score 2):

[Quantum tunneling](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html) keeps the energy of the tunneling particle the same as it had within the potential .
[image: qtunnel]

As you will find, putting realistic numbers for nuclear penetration in the calculator of the link the probabilities come out zero.

So spontaneous "turn into a nuclear bomb " is out.

Lets took "technically" : A human exposed to MeV radiation can he/she turn into a bomb?

If this were possible, there would have been a chain reaction  in Hiroshima and Nagasaki, of people turning into new bombs , instead of dying or getting radiation burns. So, experimentally the answer is No.

Humans are made up of atoms that belong to the left side of the [binding energy curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy), this means fusion not fission, which needs high temperatures and pressures to even start.A careful choice of nuclei and initial conditions  are necessary for a fusion [nuclear explosion/bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapon) to be constructed.